# Multi-Tabs - how to handle invalid fields on non active tab with save for all tabs?

Tags: tabs

I have a page with tabs. The `Save Data` will save data for all tabs. It is possible that some tabs will have input fields that will be invalid when they hit save.

How would I go about handling invalid fields? For instance, the user could hit save while on a different tab and be confused why it's not saving.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Indicate which tabs have errors, and show the errors for each section within the tab.**

[image: Multiple tab sections have errors, and one is expanded showing its error]

Optionally, if you find it suits your use case and how users interact with these tabs, you could include a summary of all the errors. Providing an overall summary of errors could be useful if the tabs are dependent on each other, or if the data is interconnected.

[image: Error summary showing errors grouped by tab header name]

Comment: Oddly enough, I actually ran into this exact same issue about an hour ago.